# How to create a VPN only accessible website?

Tags: server, intranet

I'm trying to setup an intranet on a dedicated server, it would need simple things like a sharing folders and a private website that will only be accessible trough vpn.

Now I'm really not sure how to achieve this, I kinda get the idea of setting up vpn that's fair enough but how do I set the website to only show in the intranet?

if anyone could point me to a guide or something it would be great :)

Thanks

Comment: Private DNS server that resolves `my.internalsite` to the webserver in the VPN. I, however, do not know how to set up DNS servers and such, so you'd need to research yourself, and configure your VPN to use your private DNS.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something called xampp it is a full fledged web server and it has something in its httpd.conf file that you can set to only allow users connected to your network to access the server so setup VPN and use xampp and it will work out great

Answer (score 0):

a VPN basically gives a computer in the internet access to a network . if the webserver responds to a private ip (192.x.x.x) in that network there is no way to get it from the outside.

basically you want to mount the webserver in a machine that is not the gateway to the internet (the one with the public ip provided by your ISP)

Comment: yes I can block the site from other IP in the vhost of apache, but how can I make it so that if I type "my.internalsite" in the browser it will direct automatically to the site that is only visible by me? without editing the hosts file if possible

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a complete answer, but perhaps a DNS entry on the Gateway.

 "my.internalsite.local" > 192.x.x.x 
 
Provided you're accessing it from within the network and the Gateway is your DNS Server.